# jQuery delaying an each loop and trigger

Tags: jquery

I'm using the following code to delay a trigger looping through a list of li items

```
var eleID = '';
$('.SlideSelect').each(function(i) {  

    eleID = $(this).attr('id');

    $('#'+eleID).delay(800*i).trigger('click');
});
```

However the delay does not work and just loops through.

Does anyone know why?

```
var eleID = '';
$('.SlideSelect').each(function() {  

    eleID = $(this).attr('id');

    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#'+eleID).trigger('click');
    }, 5000)
});
```

Comment: the i param in your function is the event that's being passed through the function, not an integer.

Comment: @jpea: [No, it's not](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delay is used for the animation queue.  If you want to delay anything else, you should use setTimeout.  Note the use of a separate function to allow the capture of each value in the delayed function.

```
var eleID = '';
$('.SlideSelect').each(function(i) {  

    eleID = $(this).attr('id');
    delayedTrigger( $('#'+eleID), 800*i );
});

function delayedTrigger(elem, delay)
{
    setTimeout( function() { $(elem).trigger('click'); }, delay );
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help, however I've used the edit above and it still doesnt work

Comment: No need to jquery-wrap `elem` twice.

Comment: @Brob - due to the way the variable is captured, you need to call a separate function to capture each value.  See the example I've added.

Comment: @ThiefMaster - old habits die hard.  I typically do that for functions so that it can be called with either jQuery or a DOM object reference.

Comment: @tvanfosson thanks for the help worked like a charm. Will remember the correct use of delay from now on.

Answer (score 1):

Only `fx methods` do have an implicit impact on jQuerys internal *queue*. To have any other kind of method you explicitly need to call `.queue()`:

```
$('#'+eleID).delay(800*i).queue(function( next ) {
    $(this).trigger('click');
    next();
});
```

This should work. The only thing I'm not so sure about is if `this` points to the jQuery wrapped set of invocation. I leave it to you to find out right now.

Another problem which comes along with this solution are the closures of ECMAscript. Since you're going to call that code within a loop, all those anonymous function(-contexts) will close over the `eleID` variable and reference it. To fix that, we need to invoke another context:

```
$('#'+eleID).delay(800*i).queue((function( myID ) {
    return function( next ) {
       $('#'+myID).trigger('click');
        next();
    };
}(eleID)));
```

Comment: This is going to insert it in the queue so that it happens `800*i`ms *after the item in the queue finishes*.  Assuming the queue is empty (big assumption), you should omit the `* i` if you want them 800ms apart.  Note that if other items are in the queue already, this won't result in the behavior that is desired.

Comment: yes you are right. The multiplication should be unnecesarry, good point.

Answer (score 0):

[`.delay`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) functions on *effects* (and you are trying to delay something other than an effect).

Admittedly, the documentation isn't obvious about this, beyond `.delay` being part of the *Effects* section.

Use `setTimeout` instead, in the usual fashion.

Comment: And here's an example, as others have already beaten me to the answer: http://jsfiddle.net/2Ldc9/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `delay()` for that since it only works for effects.

```
$('.SlideSelect').each(function(i) {  
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        $('#'+this.id).trigger('click');
    }, 800*i)
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var eleID = '';
var i=0;
$('.SlideSelect').each(function(event) {  
   eleID = $(this).attr('id');
   $('#'+eleID).delay(800*i).trigger('click');
   i++;
});
```

Comment: No. His `i` was fine. His `delay` is not.